# Python, using the modulo operator with nested if statements to find if the int 'x' is divisible by 3 and 5

Tags: python, if-statement, integer, modulo

how should the following code be structured in order for the correct statements to be printed when the user has input an integer?

What am i doing wrong? i have tried to change the code in so many ways with no luck.

```
x = int(input("Please enter a number:\n"))

if x % 3 == 0 and x % 5 == 0:
  print("Your number is divisible by 3 and 5.")
  if x % 3 == 0 and x % 5 == 1:
    print("Your number is divisible by 3 and NOT 5.")
  elif x % 3 == 1 and x % 5 == 0:
    print("Your number is NOT divisible by 3 and is divisible by 5.")
else:
  print("Your number is NOT divisible by 3 and 5.")
```

or

```
x = int(input("Please enter a number:\n"))

if ((x % 3 == 0) & (x % 5 == 0)):
  print("Your number is divisible by 3 and 5.")
  if ((x % 3 == 0) & (x % 5 == 1)):
    print("Your number is divisible by 3 and NOT 5.")
  elif ((x % 3 == 1) & (x % 5 == 0)):
    print("Your number is NOT divisible by 3 and is divisible by 5.")
else:
  print("Your number is NOT divisible by 3 and 5.")
```

I want the correct phrase to be displayed once the user has input their chosen integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awful shorthand but here:

```
if x % 3 == 0:
    if x % 5 == 0:
        print("Your number is divisible by 3 & 5")
    else:
        print("Your number is divisible by 3 and NOT 5.")
elif x % 5 == 0:
    print("Your number is NOT divisible by 3 and is divisible by 5.")
else:
    print("Your number is NOT divisible by 3 and 5.")
```

Also, your check where you do "x % 3 == 1" doesn't make a whole lot of sense because x % 3 could also be 2, in which case the branch wouldn't get hit.

Answer (score 1):

Each time you think you're checking for "not divisible by a number", you're actually checking "exactly one greater than a multiple of that number". The test shouldn't be `== 1`, it should be `!= 0` to cover when the remainder is anything *but* zero (a number that is not divisible by `3` might have remainders of `1` or `2`, a number not divisible by `5` might have remainders of `1`, `2`, `3` or `4`; you just care if the remainder is `0` or "something else", not `1` specifically).

You also over-indented two of your tests (so they'd only get tested when `x % 3 == 0 and x % 5 == 0`, and the tests were guaranteed to fail). Fixed code:

```
x = int(input("Please enter a number:\n"))

if x % 3 == 0 and x % 5 == 0:
    print("Your number is divisible by 3 and 5.")
elif x % 3 == 0 and x % 5 != 0:  # Changed % 5 test, dedented and made elif
    print("Your number is divisible by 3 and NOT 5.")
elif x % 3 != 0 and x % 5 == 0:  # Changed % 3 test and dedented
    print("Your number is NOT divisible by 3 and is divisible by 5.")
else:
    print("Your number is NOT divisible by 3 and 5.")
```

It's possible to simplify further (so you don't recompute `x % 3` and `x % 5` up to three times each), and Byron's answer provides a good example of that, but I left this as close to your original code as possible to demonstrate the minimal fixes (though I did PEP8-ify your indentation levels to make them easier to read: The One True Indentation is four spaces per level).